# Command line generates different hashsum than online hash generator…

Tags: command-line, hashsum

Input text: `test`

- Online MD5 hashsum generator: ***098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6***
- `echo "test" | md5sum`: ***d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249***

Also the same happens to `sha512sum` and `sha1sum`.

Why does Linux and an online generator generate different hashes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of these is the hash of "`test`" and one of them is the hash of "`test\n`".

```
$ printf 'test' | md5sum
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6  -
$ printf 'test\n' | md5sum
d8e8fca2dc0f896fd7cb4cb0031ba249  -
```

[`echo` outputs a newline character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) after its arguments.